# python tkinter событие нажатия textbox

Tags: python, tkinter, события, textbox

Изучаю Python. Имеется форма, созданная с помощью tkinter. Интересует возможность реализации события, в котором при нажатии enter в текстбоксе, выполнялась бы какая-либо команда.

Например:

В текстбоксе пользователь  вводит "Hello", нажимает enter и выполняется print(значение из textbox).

P.S. варианты с нажатием на кнопку не предлагать. Ими и так забиты все запросы в гугле и ютубе.

Мне требуется именно нажатие на enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текстбокс:

...

параметры тексбокса

...

```
self.tb_text.bind('<Return>', self.insertTextbox)
```

Функция:

```
def insertTextbox(self,event):
  str = tb_text.get()
  print(str)
```